# Какие есть плюсы и минусы от использования самописной cms?

Tags: cms

И какие есть плюсы от готового решения ?
Что безопасней своя cms или готовая ?

Comment: Не реклама, но довольно наглядно: https://files.myrusakov.ru/video/php2.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плюсы своей cms:

- Вы сами написали cms, повышается чсв, можно в портфолио записать.
- узнали много нового.
- возможно, cms способна потреблять минимум ресурсов, так как нет лишнего.
- скорее всего нет никаких закладок.
- взлом сторонним скрипкидиссом немного затрудняется - у него нет готовых скриптов.

Минусы своей cms:

- Ее нужно писать и фиксить. Найти специалистов по ней будет сложно.
- Вполне возможно, что в ней есть ошибки, возможно грубые и детские.

Плюсы сторонней популярной cms:

- скорее всего можно сделать рабочее решение за пару часов.
- можно найти много людей, которые с ней работали и могут помочь решить проблему.
- есть множество скриптов и рецептов на различные случаи жизни.
- активно проверяются сообществом на уязвимости и фиксятся.

Минусы сторонней популярной cms:

- если нашли уязвимость, то скорее всего быстро могут взломать в "автоматическом режиме"
- нет гарантий, что нет бекдоров и язвимостей
- в расширениях могут быть дополнительные загвоздки.

Comment: что такое чсв ?

Comment: @LenovoID, Чувство Собственного Величия/Важности.